# Yii2 active form, please wait message while submitting with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, dialog, yii2, active-form

I'm using Yii2's advanced template, and looking for a way to display a dialog with 'Please wait...' message while sending an login form to the server.

Here is my active form code:

```
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'id' => $model->formName(),
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
            ]); ?>
                <fieldset>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'username', [
                        'inputOptions' => [
                            'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('username'),
                        ],
                    ])->label(false); ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'password', [
                        'inputOptions' => [
                            'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('password'),
                        ],
                    ])->label(false)->passwordInput() ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox() ?>

                    <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
                </fieldset>
            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

And my server side action:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    } else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I'm successfully validating the inputs / sending the form, but need to display a dialog, so if the connection is slow the user will get an idea that the form is actually sending and needs more time to complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `ActiveForm` you need to use according events. Currently it's managed with Javascript (see [official upgrade info](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/UPGRADE.md)).

```
$('#myform').on('ajaxBeforeSend', function (event, jqXHR, settings) {
    // Activate waiting label
}).on('ajaxComplete', function (event, jqXHR, textStatus) {
    // Deactivate waiting label
});
```

Here is more detailed info about these two events.

**ajaxBeforeSend:**

> ajaxBeforeSend event is triggered before sending an AJAX request for
>   AJAX-based validation.
>
> The signature of the event handler should be:
>
> function (event, jqXHR, settings)
>
> where
>
> - event: an Event object.
> - jqXHR: a jqXHR object
> - settings: the settings for the AJAX request

**ajaxComplete:**

> ajaxComplete event is triggered after completing an AJAX request for
>   AJAX-based validation. The signature of the event handler should be:
>
> function (event, jqXHR, textStatus)
>
> where
>
> - event: an Event object.
> - jqXHR: a jqXHR object
> - textStatus: the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror").

Also check [this extension](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-spinner), maybe it will be useful for this purpose.

Comment: I'm going to try those two events. The extension looks quite useful too, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following javascript solution to listen to 'before submit'

```
$('body').on('beforeSubmit', 'form#yourFormId', function() {
    $('#loading').show(); //show the loading div
    var form = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    type: 'post',
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        // do processing of data
         $('#loading').hide(); //hide it
    }
  });

return false;
```

});

You will need to add a div with id loading and use suitable css for that

```
<div id='loading'> Loading ... </div>
```

Adding a maunal  close button to this div is also recommended for cases with network fluctuations

Comment: As I understood he want to use it with `ActiveForm` AJAX validation.

Comment: @arogachev, in that case, another statement can be added to the beforeSubmit Hook `$('#form-id').yiiActiveForm('validate');`

Comment: But the AJAX request is consructed automatically with `yii.activeForm.js`.

Comment: @arogachev: exactly, the issue is that I can't find a way to properly modify the ajax request as it is automatically constructed.